# Laravel model not using custom create method

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to define a custom create method in my `Image` model to upload the file to storage and give it a unique file name.

I can't seem to find anything since 5.4 about the procedure to create the custom method. I've checked the docs and I (think I) am doing it as they say. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade "The create & forceCreate Methods".

My model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'caption',
    'path'
];

public static function create(array $attributes, $image, $extension, $folder = null)
{
    die("It died.");
    $attributes['path'] = FileNameGenerator::getNewFilePath($extension);

    Storage::disk('s3')->put( $folder . $attributes['path'], File::get($image));

    $model = static::query()->create($attributes);
    return $model;
}
```

Where I'm calling the model:

```
Auth::user()->image()->create([], $image, $extension, config('app.profile_pictures_path'));
```

I'm getting an error that `path` doesn't have a default value.

It's as if the method is being completely ignored as the `die` method isn't called. I've also tried changing the function's parameters to look exactly like what is shown in the docs but that still yields the same result.

Apologies if this is a newbie question. I really can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Have you tried hooking into the beforeCreate as an alternative?

Comment: You may find it useful:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Comment: @MyLibary Thanks a lot. I think I will have to do that.

Comment: @MyLibary How would I pass variables into the create method which would get passed into the creating event?